# How can I display HTML-Code with PHP?

Tags: php, html, display

I have a Login and I want to display a class if someone keeps a field empty. The if-part works good. By pressing on the button, the user shell stay at that page and then the error-class shell appear at the top just like here: http://www.loltyler1.com/contact

The class/HTML-code that i want to display:

```
<div class="empty">Please don't leave any field empty!</div>
```

The PHP-code:

```
if (empty($username) || empty($password)){  

    echo("<script>window.location = '../login.php?login=empty';</script>");
    echo '<div class="empty">Please do not leave any field empty!</div>';   
    exit();
}
```

Without the first echo he moves to my include php file instead of staying on login.php. But with this line the second echo doesnt appear.

Comment: With HTML5 you do not need JavaScript. Just add a "required" property to each input.

Comment: *" I just don't know how to display HTML stuff"* if you `echo`ed it, it should be visible. Can you plaese rephrase your question? As it is it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: If you redirect to `login.php?login=empty` how will that HTML display???

Comment: I want people to see my new car at my house but I sent the people to my brother's house, why can't the people see my car?

Comment: If I leave out the "login.php?login=empty" he opens my php include file. So I want him to go to that page first and then he displays the class on that new page

Comment: Then you should put the class in the other page.

Comment: Thats my include file. I want to stay at that  page and dont open my include by clicking that button

Comment: @AbraCadaver that example doesnt really fits because I am already at login.php and by clicking that button i just refresh the page and display that class

Answer (score 0):

You're echo-ing the div correctly. But, as @AbraCadaver said in the comments, you're redirecting to `login.php?login=empty` with that first echo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't display any of the relevant code.  You need to paste all of your form code for this type of question.

But, to answer your question without any type of code...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

The php code

```
if ( (empty($_POST['username'])) || (empty($_POST['password'])) ) { $error = "please fill in all form fields"; }
if ( (!isset($error)) || ($error == "") ) {  // rest of your php code to check and log them in }
```

then to show error

```
if ($error != "") { echo '<div class="error">'. $error .'</div>'; }
```

### **to use your code**

I don't recommend doing it like this because theres no reason to refresh the page again and change the url.  But, if this is the way you want to do it, before echoing out the div for error, you need to put some variation of this...

```
$errordetection = $_GET['login'];
if ( (isset($errordetection)) && ($errordetection == "empty") ) {  echo '<div class="empty">Please do not leave any field empty!</div>'; }
```

### For the styling to display the div at the top,

```
.error { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; padding: 20px; text-align: center; }
```

or

```
.error { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; padding: 20px; text-align: center; }
```

### EDIT

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username">
<?php if ($user_error == 1) { echo '<div class="error">Please enter username</div>'; } ?>
    <input type="password" name="password">
<?php if ($pass_error == 1) { echo '<div class="error">Please enter password</div>'; } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
```

The php code

```
  if  (empty($_POST['username'])) { $user_error = 1; $error = "please fill in all form fields"; }

if  (empty($_POST['password'])) { $pass_error = 1; $error = "please fill in all form fields"; }
    if ( (!isset($error)) || ($error == "") ) {  // rest of your php code to check and log them in }
```

Comment: So again: If someone clicks on the button with empty fields, a message shell appear at the top (the class "empty"). The issue I have is that after clicking on the button he opens the include file instead of staying at the page and just display the message. So I tried to direct the user to the page ( like a refresh) and then show the message. http://www.loltyler1.com/contact here is an example

Comment: You can do it that way; however, that sounds like javascript/jquery to have a message appear on the page.  Or can can use <input type="text" required> to require the fields be entered before submit being pressed.  Or you can do my method, refresh the page to itself, do the checks,a nd then if everything passes the way you want it to, then you can do a meta refresh to the page you want it to go to.

Comment: Or you can create a "process" page that processes data and sends users to whichever page you want them to go based on errors or no errors

Comment: if this helped, please accept answer or revise question so I can try to answer

Comment: "<input type="text" required>" works but I also want to add some diffrent error messages like "invalid username" or something like this and I just search a simple method with JavaScript/PHP to display that. Could it work if I create a function that changes the visibilty from the class and i call this function in my php if part?

Comment: yes.  All you need to do is `.error { display: none; }` and then javascript to change display or visibility.  I also updated my answer to reflect if there are user errors.  You'll have to modify for what you want it to display if user not found in database, etc.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("error").style.display = "block";` is one example.  Probably needs some work though

Comment: You can run place that code inside a `<script>` tag in the php code where errors are found.

Comment: does that answer your question?